# Parsing embedded elements with XPATH

Tags: xpath

```
<cpc:note type="note">
<cpc:note-paragraph>This subclass 
    <cpc:u>covers</cpc:u>: 
    <cpc:subnote type="bullet">
        <cpc:note-paragraph>equipment for the care, culture or rearing of all animals, or for obtaining their products, unless provided for elsewhere,e.g. milking 
            <cpc:class-ref scheme="cpc">A01J</cpc:class-ref>, shoeing animals 
            <cpc:class-ref scheme="cpc">A01L</cpc:class-ref>, veterinary devices 
            <cpc:class-ref scheme="cpc">A61D</cpc:class-ref>, culture of animal cells 
            <cpc:class-ref scheme="cpc">C12M</cpc:class-ref>, 
            <cpc:class-ref scheme="cpc">C12N</cpc:class-ref>;
        </cpc:note-paragraph>
        <cpc:note-paragraph>methods of breeding animals or new animal breeds.</cpc:note-paragraph>
    </cpc:subnote>
</cpc:note-paragraph>
```

Really having a difficult time parsing this XML node.
I'm retrieving the particular note elements correctly but unsure as to how to parse "inner" nodes. This is from the EPO OPS api and they appear to embed display logic within their code. So one could think of this as html with .

I'm curious how to return the above in plain text for now, ignoring those subelements using XPATH

current attempt uses `./cpc:note-paragraph/text()`

Comment: What do you use to run your XPath expression? What is this ~x"expression"Sl syntax?

Comment: @ideafixxxer yeah sorry, I'm using Elixir SweetXml library. the string is the important part. Best guess is I loop over all child elements and check element names `name()` function surprising not working atm.

Comment: Actually, parsing the XML is trivial: just throw it an an XML parser. It's how to extract information from the XML once it's been parsed that's your problem. And my problem in helping you is that it's not clear to me what information you are trying to extract.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with Elixir, but you need to check two things:

1. Namespace. You must declare the namespace for cpc: somewhere to use in your expression. In .NET we use XmlNamespaceManager that we pass to XPath evalution method.
2. Check your expression if it actually goes all the way to the cpc:note-paragraph element.

In C# I can write something like this to find all text node under the paragraphs.

```
var x = XElement.Load(reader);
var xmn = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
xmn.AddNamespace("cpc", "http://cpc-namespace");
var nodes = x.XPathEvaluate("//cpc:note-paragraph//text()", xmn);
```